# Error on search filter for react ant design table

Tags: reactjs, antd

Table throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined[object Object]`
whenever I am doing a search on the field. I've attached a
[code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/r048zp13n)

Can anyone tell me what have I done wrong?

Comment: Can't duplicate. All the searches work fine for me. But that error is saying you're trying to call `toString()` on an undefined item. Check your`record[dataIndex]` and `text` variables.

Comment: @liren-yeo that gave me the idea. the records is a nested array `name.first` and 'dob.age' hence the search would not work...however I do wonder what's a good way to solve this problem

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you mentioned. What should I do to make the error appear?

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when you have null data in your column.  For example, if one one of your rows is missing an age value and you attempt to search that column it will throw the error.  Unsure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i faced same type of error, i fixed this issue.

issue is:

```
{ onFilter: (value, record) => record[dataIndex].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) }
```

After fixing the using if condition

```
{ onFilter: (value, record) => { if (record[dataIndex]) return record[dataIndex].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) } }
```